# jest rejects every directive starting with mat- (the new md- prefix) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

Though I have all the MaterialModules imported and the components compile without error Jest cannot compile: "If <mat- ... > is an Angular Component, make sure it is imported ..."

Anybody similar problems? Any workarounds?

Comment: Can you show the code and the error to have people be able to see what you are trying?

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to construct a sample. By doing so I found the answer (below).

Answer (score 0):

All used directives have to be declared in the .spec files. In case of <mat-card>

- `import MatCard from '@angular/material'`
- `TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      MatCard,
    ],`